# Sum formula for the $\Omega$ constant

Tags: summation, lambert-w

I was looking a bit around, and was interested in the konstant $\Omega$. It is defined as number satisfying the equation 
$$ x e^x = 1 $$
Now, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant), gives an reccurence relation for the constant as

$$ \Omega_{n+1} = \frac{1 + \Omega_n}{1 + \exp(\Omega_n)} $$

My question is, can this recurrence relation be rewritten as a sum ?

Comment: You can use the definition $\Omega=W(1)$, where $W$ is the Lambert function, and its expansion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions